# Column cannot be null when table has a trigger on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-5.7

I do not know if this is expected behaviour or a bug but it seems incorrect. Using MySQL `5.7.9` from the [Ubuntu 14.04 ondrej PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.7).

Summary: an operation which should raise a warning (inserting an implicit `NULL` into a `not null` column) raises an error, *only* if the table has a trigger defined.

```
 select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

show global variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

show variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

create table _test (col_1 varchar(20) not null, col_2 varchar(20) not null) engine=myisam charset=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

show columns from _test;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col_1 | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| col_2 | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 insert into _test (col_1) values ('abc');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

^^^^^^^^^ This is expected behaviour ^^^^^^^^^

delimiter $$

create trigger `insert_test` before insert on `_test` for each row begin set NEW.col_1 = concat(NEW.col_1, '+test'); end$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

delimiter ;

insert into _test (col_1) values ('abc');
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'col_2' cannot be null

^^^^^^^^^ This is UNexpected behaviour ^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus the same command in the same mode has a different end-state when a trigger is set.

Can anyone see a mistake in this, has anyone experienced similar or is this a bug in the release?

#### Update

Having tested the same process in `5.6.19` (also on Ubuntu 14.04) the final line returns:

```
insert into _test (col_1) values ('abc');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Which once again is expected behaviour.

#### Update 2

This has been [submitted as a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79266) to the MySQL development team and is now at *verified* status.

Comment: So `col_2` is never actually set but `NOT NULL`, so MySQL is right to complain!?

Comment: It is not right to raise an error; it should raise a warning if the `sql_mode` value does not have `strict_trans_tables`. Also, it does not raise an error in the first instance, it raises a warning. It only raises an error once the table has a trigger.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I did notice this passage in the [CREATE TRIGGER reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html): "MySQL stores the sql_mode system variable setting in effect when a trigger is created, and always executes the trigger body with this setting in force, regardless of the current server SQL mode when the trigger begins executing."

Comment: Interesting; I wonder if it is possible to view that. Though in the reproduction all the commands are run with the same mode in effect.

Comment: Looks like there's an `SQL_MODE` column in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers-table.html) table that might be worth looking at

Comment: Check: [BEFORE triggers and NOT NULL columns in MySQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/before-triggers-and-not-null-columns-in-mysql/).

Comment: @M1ke Is it possible that the sql_mode is different in the session and the global scope and the trigger queries the global, not the session variable?

Comment: @wchiquito I think the resolution for that bug has caused this one

Comment: @shadow I have tested that and added the results into the code; all three ways I know to check return the same mode

Comment: @DaveJones I have checked the mode in triggers and it is the same as the modes that appear for those queries

Comment: Just finished reading the page linked to by @wchiquito - it certainly does sound related to this and I'd concur with your suspicion that the behaviour is probably related to that fix. May be worth opening an issue for it.

Comment: I have [submitted it as a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79266)